# SQLAlchemy using wildcards or ILIKE for update statments

Tags: regex, sqlalchemy, sql-like

I need to use `ilike` in an update statement but it returns this error when I try:

> InvalidRequestError: Could not evaluate current criteria in Python. Specify 'fetch' or False for the synchronize_session parameter.

for this code:

```
meta.Session.query(i.mappedClass).filter(getattr(i.mappedClass, j).ilike("%"+userid+"%")).update({j:newUserId})
```

I could use something like regexp_replace but it's a bit overkill. I just want the update to accommodate case insensitivity and spaces at either end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok that was frustrating!

The simple workaround I found was this:

```
for i in model.dataTables:
for j in i.idColumn:
    rows = meta.Session.query(i.mappedClass).filter(getattr(i.mappedClass, j).ilike("%"+userid+"%")).all()
     for row in rows:
         setattr(row, j, newuserid)
meta.Session.commit()
```

Comment: This is not just a workaround, but a different way of doing it. Your first approach would basically execute the `SQL UPDATE` statement directly on the SQL backend, whereas the workaround would load every row into memory as model object, update it in-memory and later commit the changes to the SQL backend. If this is a maintenance type of operation, I recon the first approach would still be better, especially if `newuserid` can be calculated from `userid` on the SQL backend.

Comment: I dont want to have to execute the statement on every loop. The second way works better for me as the user cannot interrupt the loop half way through an update.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# test columns
userid = "dUmMy"
j = "name" # name of the column
mappedTable = i.mappedClass.__table__ # assuming use of Declarative. if not, mappedTable is the Table object mapped to i.mappedClass
_stmt = (mappedTable.update().where(getattr(i.mappedClass, j).ilike("%"+ userid +"%")).
            values({getattr(i.mappedClass, j): func.lower(getattr(i.mappedClass, j))})
        )
session.execute(_stmt)
```

produces SQL:

```
UPDATE person SET name=lower(person.name) WHERE lower(person.name) LIKE lower(?)
```

In fact you can update all records in the table by just removing the `where` clause:

```
_stmt = mappedTable.update().values({getattr(i.mappedClass, j): func.lower(getattr(i.mappedClass, j))})
session.execute(_stmt)
```

which produces SQL like this:

```
UPDATE person SET name=lower(person.name)
```

Comment: ideally I wanted to stay away from session.execute, but Ill have a mess around with what youve given here and see what I can get

Comment: I do not see how `session.execute()` is at the end different from the `query(...).update()`?

Comment: Because the query is in a loop and could cause issues with opening multiple connections

Comment: ... then it would look like you are even better off using `session.execute(...)` or?