# How to use ilike and wildcard pattern in python psycopg2?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2, quoting

I already referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901402/sqlalchemy-using-wildcards-or-ilike-for-update-statments) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363836/postgresql-ilike-query-with-sqlalchemy) but it doesn't help

I am trying to write the below code

```
import psycopg2
param_dic = {
    "host"      : "localhost",
    "database"  : "test",
    "user"      : "test",
    "password"  : "****"
}
conn = psycopg2.connect(**param_dic)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from test where code in ("0091","0092","0FY00Z0","0FY00Z1","0FY00Z2","5051","5059")')
```

In the above `cursor execute` command, whether I use `single quote` or `double quotes` I get the error as shown below

> ndefinedColumn                           Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 cursor.execute('select * from test where code in
> ("0091","0092","0FY00Z0","0FY00Z1","0FY00Z2","5051","5059")')
>
> UndefinedColumn: column "0091" does not exist LINE 1: ...from
> test where code in ("0091","00...

When I change the quotes to `single quote`, I get the below error

> cursor.execute('select * from test where code in
> ('0091','0092','0FY00Z0','0FY00Z1','0FY00Z2','5051','5059')')
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid token

When I try to use `ilike` operator, I get the below error

```
cursor.execute ('select code from test where long_title ilike '%live%' and long_title ilike '%ransplan%'')
```

> NameError: name 'live' is not defined

**But all the above query works perfectly fine in my pgadmin postgresql editor. So there is no issue with the SQL in its native form but when I try to use them in python using `cursor.execute`, I am encountering issues.**

Can you help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgresql requires that string values are quoted with single quotes.

Python strings can be bounded with either single quotes (`'...'`), double-quotes (`"..."`) or tripled single or double quotes (`'''...'''`).

To keep Postgresql happy, use single quotes to quote the values in the query, and bound the query string with one of the other types.

```
cursor.execute("""select * from test where code in ('0091','0092','0FY00Z0','0FY00Z1','0FY00Z2','5051','5059')""")

cursor.execute ("""select code from test where long_title ilike '%live%' and long_title ilike '%ransplan%'""")
```

It's common, but not obligatory, to use triple-quotes for SQL queries, as they will work when the query contains single-quoted values or double-quoted identifiers.

Comment: Related: [How to use variables in SQL statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python?r=SearchResults&s=2|25.3410)